# Does it make sense to repair typos in posts (I would like, but suggestion canceling)?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, search, quality-improvement, typographical-error

Does it make sense to repair typos in posts (title and content)? Do you use fuzzy search algorithm during searching?

Is it because it is probably not needed to update typos? I am thinking about these typo types:

- vulnarabilities vs vulnerabilities
- mesage vs message
- pithon vs python
- pipy vs pypi

I would like to save effort and avoid suggestion cancelling.

Why did I get a few typo edit rejections with a note that type revisions block capacities of reviewers?

> Moderator Private Message: Please stop formulaically find/replacing a single typo via suggested edits. If you really want to fix these typos via suggestions, at least fix some other issues while you're at it (as one example, the post title "show Toast mesage till video installation and play it" needs some serious work beyond just having a typo). Otherwise, please wait until you can edit without review. Suggested edits must be reviewed by two people, and these edits take up valuable volunteer time to review, as well as blocking other people from submitting more substantive edits.

Comment: Please research how & when to edit in the [help] & the [privilege help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges). Please always research before considering posting a question.

Comment: Related reason: [suggested edit queue is full](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=suggested%20edit%20queue%20full%20is%3aq&searchOn=3)

Comment: The logic, when accept/reject edit suggestions is not very easy and clear (it is my experience, but I can live with that).

Comment: What is "_I would like, but suggestion canceling_" supposed to mean?

Comment: @khelwood See "Moderator Private Message" in original question. It is possible to repair type ... only in case 2.000 reputation or in case that you can update more things in text ... in other cases - the typo repairs will be canceled (it is my understanding and it is based on private message without clear and transparent visualization for all)

Comment: "Why did I get a few typo edit rejections with a note that type revisions block capacities of reviewers?" Well, when you tried submitting those edits, you were sent a message that told you "Please stop formulaically find/replacing a single typo via suggested edits. If you really want to fix these typos via suggestions, at least fix some other issues while you're at it". My best guess is that *you should stop formulaically find/replacing a single typo via suggested edits*, and that *if you really want to fix these typos via suggestions, you should at least fix some other issues*.

Comment: If a moderator telling you straight out what is wrong with what you did, does not explain to you what is wrong with what you did, then how are we supposed to say anything else that would help? If you did not read what the moderator told you, then why should we expect you to read what we tell you?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, why private message? Why not as common rule, why not do revision/approval that small typo (one symbol) only with one approval, ... do not be sheep (use brain)

Comment: You were private messaged because you repeatedly did something wrong, and therefore needed to be told about it, and there was no other way to tell you - the problem was detected by moderators, not by the site software, so they are the ones who needed to talk to you. It was already explained to you in other comments why your proposal would not work. Aside from that: to be perfectly honest, there are numerous typos and grammatical errors in your own writing here; I would not consider you qualified to make these edits, based on what I have seen so far.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, dummy one approval role for all and it generates issue ... nice. It is better to keep typos than change approval rules ... it can be. I opened this point because it seems unlogical.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, the issue is one approval rule for all not the typo repair. Please, read last answer for this question also.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, is it really only issue for  one editor (for me) or is it common issue? I do not know, please tell.

Comment: No, *python* should be *[Python](https://pmortensen.eu/EditOverflow/_Wordlist/EditOverflowList_latest.html#Python)* (unless it is actually the name of an executable; the name of the executable will be `python3` on some systems (e.g., later versions of Ubuntu)). *pypi* should be *[PyPI](https://pmortensen.eu/EditOverflow/_Wordlist/EditOverflowList_latest.html#PyPI)*. [More](https://pmortensen.eu/EditOverflow/_Wordlist/EditOverflowList_latest.html#vulnerabilities) [variations](https://pmortensen.eu/EditOverflow/_Wordlist/EditOverflowList_latest.html#message).

Comment: @PeterMortensen, do you see the same issues in case of switch-off case sensitive check?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fact that text can be found by a fuzzy search engine nonetheless is not an argument for not fixing typos. Fix everything you can find to improve everyone's reading experience.

Comment: But I got a few time typo cancel with note, that it blocks capacities of validators. I would like to repair typo also.

Comment: I don't recognize that verbiage. Can you link to a rejected edit?

Comment: e.g. rejected post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27999302/show-toast-mesage-till-video-installation-and-play-it  and Moderator Private Message see https://stackoverflow.com/users/message/106083#106083

Comment: Content of Moderator Private Message: Please stop formulaically find/replacing a single typo via suggested edits. If you really want to fix these typos via suggestions, at least fix some other issues while you're at it (as one example, the post title "show Toast mesage till video installation and play it" needs some serious work beyond just having a typo). Otherwise, please wait until you can edit without review. Suggested edits must be reviewed by two people, and these edits take up valuable volunteer time to review, as well as blocking other people from submitting more substantive edits.

Comment: Please link to the rejected edit itself, I can't find it from the post link. And I can't access your private messages. If you want help deciphering what the mods meant, consider posting the relevant quotes within your question, if that is allowed.

Comment: Ah. No, you should not enter known typos in search and then go fix that typo alone in years-old posts.

Comment: It is fine for new posts and bad for old posts ... or (what is old post, how old). Can you better explain it? But e.g. the word 'vulnerabilities' ... is very important without view if it is old or not (I guess).

Comment: If you start editing a post, fix everything. Don't go find old posts to fix one typo.

Comment: What does it mean "wait until you can edit without review"?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing: _"If a user has less than 2,000 reputation, the suggested edit is placed in a review queue. Two accept or reject votes are required to remove the suggested edit from the queue and either apply the edit to the post or discard it.

Users with more than 2,000 reputation are considered trusted community members, and can edit posts without going through the review process."_

Comment: Is this my initial question bad/irrelevant?

Comment: I think the problem is not with the typos indeed, but with how you've been fixing them. Fixing typos is good, but filling up the edit review queue with typo edits isn't.

Comment: Perhaps reference the canonical MSO post about comprehensive edits suggestions? (I don't have it at hand right now.)

Answer (score 13):

While I agree with the existing answer, let me expand the intent of the moderator's message.

When you make an edit suggestion, you effectively ask two other people to do some work (which is, review your edit). While the result is an overall improvement of content on the site, it's achieved with relatively much effort - 3 people were involved. If the content still requires additional effort (e.g. not all typos were fixed), the situation is very disappointing.

To make this less likely, the community invented the principle of "edit all or nothing". You either fix all the problems you can (typos, grammar, formatting, etc) or do nothing. If you are too lazy (or just unable) to improve all aspects of the post, leave it to other people.

Note that if you suggest an edit, while it waits for approval, it's impossible to edit the post further. If people see that your suggested edit could be improved, they can choose an option called "reject and edit", which throws away your changes, and lets people do better. Maybe that's what's happened.

Note also that many people can edit posts without needing review. In this case, it may be acceptable to do small incomplete changes, because the cost of these is small: you don't require work from additional people. However, people usually apply the "all or nothing" principle in this case too (for other reasons).

Comment: Why not to allow to do small typo changes (update one or two symbols) only with one person for approval?

Comment: How do you propose the system detects all typo only questions to differentiate this? Even a small edit can be significantly change the meaning of a post so detecting typo only is non trivial.

Comment: @cafce25, my proposal is, for one symbol edit (in case that spellchecker also say typo mistake) the approval can be only from side of one person (not three persons)

Comment: Only 2 reviewers need to accept currently so that's only a little (2 -> 1 reviewer) improvement with a somewhat high techincal burden (special case instead of just do the same thing for everything) for something that doesn't affect the overall quality that much, I don't really see the point why you can't just put the time in to fix everything with your edit.

Comment: @cafce25, the key issue is, huge effort for approvals ... it is the way, how to decrease it. I am not sure that all editors will do perfect revisions based on your recommendation. If the effort can be decreased by 50% ... it is woow for me personally.

Comment: @cafce25, you can see lazy editors, lazy moderators, ... the perfect way for automatization in clear cases. I do not see extra huge development effort.

Comment: @JIST: The problem with any automatic system is false positives. 99% accuracy is not enough. Especially as tech words introduce ambiguity. Example: [blade](https://pmortensen.eu/EditOverflow/_Wordlist/EditOverflowList_latest.html#Blade)

Comment: @PeterMortensen, can you do automatization only for part of cases where match is 100%?