# Why does a limit to pending edits exist?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I was reviewing the First Answers Queue recently and since the answers like always were badly formatted, I got to edit the answers. So after a few edits, I see another answer which needs editing and I prepare a nice edit. When I try to submit it, SO says that I have too many pending edits. This got me thinking, why does the limit exist? After all we reviewers are given the task to fix bad answers so why limit it?

Comment: Well, someone has to review the edits, so it doesn't make much sense to keep the back-log ever growing. Keep in mind that it gets better when you hit 2k, since your edits don't need reviews after that point.

Comment: The pending suggestions *per user* is limited to 5. The suggested edits queue's limit is 500. Which means that 100 motivated editors with <2k rep can fill it entirely. If we drop the per-user limit, then much fewer slightly more motivated editors can fill up the suggested edits queue. And not that the queue *is already* almost constantly at its limit. It's an ongoing issue that has yet to be properly addressed.

Comment: You might want to read up on "back pressure" in the context of software. It's a useful concept to know well past SO.

Comment: Good job on the suggestions. Those suggestions are sufficiently comprehensive, unlike most edit suggestions. Minor: some of the tech words could have been covered as well, e.g., [React Native](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(JavaScript_library)#React_Native) and [Apache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server).

Comment: As an example of why limiting edits - we really don't need thousands of spellchecking edits for fixing "thank In advanced" to "Thanks in advance" (or similar like discussed in recent meta [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423967/does-it-make-sense-to-repair-typos-in-posts-i-would-like-but-suggestion-cancel))...

Comment: *It's an ongoing issue that has yet to be properly addressed.* Thanos tried to address it, but folks complained about that, too.

Answer (score 5):

Quality control and to avoid wasting everyone's time mainly i.e. if you're suggesting poor quality edits because

- you don't fix everything with the post
- you edit code in question when you generally should not
- you introduce new issues because your corrections are not themselves correct

we'd like to stop you and warn you that you're not doing it right before

1. you waste your time creating hundreds of suggestions that will all be rejected for the same reason
2. you waste our time reviewing hundreds of suggestions that we simply reject

There's also an overall limit on pending edits (as well as a personal limit) so that pending edits don't take too long to review as again we want to give people feedback in a timely manner.

Unfortunately because spammers try to introduce spam via edit suggestions, we do need to actively review all edits rather than merely accepting them and reviewing edits is not a terribly popular activity so the edit queue is often full.

Comment: Perhaps you should earn more per-user suggestions based on net approved edits (approved minus rejected) similar to how you earn more daily flags for more net helpful flags (helpful minus declined).

Comment: @user16217248 you could always suggest that via a new meta question although having people be able to suggest more edits will simply make the queue full more of the time. What is needed is a) some way to encourage more reviews b) some way to discourage poor quality suggestions i.e. increase supply and/or decrease demand on the queue throughput.

Comment: Maybe to encourage more reviews we could decrease the min rep to review edits. We only need 5000 rep to review tag edits but 20000 to bypass the queue. Maybe 1000 or 1500 users should be able to review edits, but only 2000 users can bypass the queue.

Comment: @user16217248 tag edits suffer from massive plagiarism problems. They are best left as a separate issue.